# Arduino --> Android bluetooth communication (receive text with App Inventor)

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, communication, app-inventor

I'm creating an Arduino based drone that can be controlled through an Android application.
In order to improve the user experience, I'd like to show the accelerometer/compass sensor's values on the application, so I need to send them from Arduino to Android, via Bluetooth. The values are simple integer number between 0 and 180.

The best solution I thought is to concatenate all the values (separated with a comma) in one string, and send it to the app, that will separate the single values (the string will be sent only when the app require it, in this case when a 'z' byte is received by Arduino).

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    if (Serial.read()=='z'){
        Serial.println(String((int)sensor1) + ',' + String((int)sensor2) + ',' + String((int)sensor3));
    }  
 }
```

Here are the App Inventor blocks:
[image: App Inventor pseudo-code]

It seems that the values are being received quite well, but there is a critical issue: somethimes the string is not received well, and that cause a lot of errors. Sometimes the received string is (for example) 10,10,10, but somethimes it is 10,10,1010 or just 10,10 ecc...

I also tried to send the values one by one, but the result was nearly the same.
I even tried to set 'numberOfBytes' to -1, using a delimiter byte, but this also was not succesful unfortunately.

I getting quite mad, so I hope there is another way to send thoose integers to Android, or to fix the system I'm already using.

Comment: see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/cJamYeLZ82U/nP6AdEbcKJUJ) in the **App Inventor forum** or do a search for more information in the forum there

Comment: thanks! in the forum you suggested I found the solution for this problem!

Answer (score 1):

I used Serial.print to send each result and then used `Serial.write('>');` as the end marker.

In `appinventor` designer window  set the Delimiter byte for Bluetooth client to 62 (the ASCII value for  the > character ).

In the blocks window, use Bluetooth `cliant1.Receive` text and set number of bytes to -1

App invented will then read until a delimiter is found.

However it will cause the app to hang if it doesn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are not signaling the end of the string
I used his example on a project and was something like this:

```
while(Serial.available()>0){
  Serial.println(String((int)Sensor1) + ',' + String((int)Sensor2)+ ',');
}
```

If you compare the two codes the difference will be a " , " the most at the end of the print and it solved the problem for you sitad